# Regex match multiple lines before and after word delimited by start and end words

Tags: html, regex, twig, opencart-3, ocmod

I am wanting to search for `{{ upc }}` and start the capture not from the `<div` immediately ahead of the match but the 2nd `<div` ahead of the match i.e. `<div class="form-group">` and capture not up to the first `</div>` after the match but the 2nd i.e closing `</div>` or up to the start of the next `<div class="form-group">` (depending on how you look at it)

Here is the sample HTML/Twig template I am wanting to search and replace.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-sku"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ help_sku }}">{{ entry_sku }}</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="sku" value="{{ sku }}" placeholder="{{ entry_sku }}" id="input-sku" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-upc"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ help_upc }}">{{ entry_upc }}</span></label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="upc" value="{{ upc }}" placeholder="{{ entry_upc }}" id="input-upc" class="form-control"/>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-ean"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ help_ean }}">{{ entry_ean }}</span></label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="ean" value="{{ ean }}" placeholder="{{ entry_ean }}" id="input-ean" class="form-control"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

The expected regex match is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-upc"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ help_upc }}">{{ entry_upc }}</span></label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" name="upc" value="{{ upc }}" placeholder="{{ entry_upc }}" id="input-upc" class="form-control"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

All help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @samthegolden I'm starting with `/^.*(?={{ sku }}).*/gm` on regex101 although that is probably too vague for a starting point. I will keep fumbling and if I solve post it here but I suspect a regex master will beat me to it!

Comment: edit the post with your code

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can try is to use a negative lookahead to filter out the things you do not wish to be included in your match.  For instance, matching a `<div`, followed by anything and then another `<div`, can match things like `<div></div><div>`.

Instead, what you can say is to match `<div`, followed by anything - as long as it is not `</div>` - and then another `<div`.

```
<div    (?:(?!</div>).)*    <div
```

Then, you can insert that same subpattern anywhere in your expression where you'd normally write `.*`.  In this particular case, you can repeat that to make sure you're not hitting a closing div before the `UPC` and *then* continue with the `{{ UPC }}` portion.

```
<div(?:(?!</div>).)*<div    (?:(?!</div>).)*    {{ upc }}    .*?</div>\s*</div>
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvL3uU/1)

Comment: Perfect and much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `div`'s you want and then absorb everything inside them and exclude the rest.

`[\w\W]` means match words and non-words. It matches newline characters for instance, which `*` does not.

`[\w\W]*(<div[\w\W]*?<div[\w\W]*?{{ sku }}[\w\W]*?<\/div>[\w\W]*?<\/div>)[\w\W]*`

Comment: thanks but it's far too greedy with too many steps. The HTML/Twig code is just a small part of the whole document. Unfortunately this regex matches everything before and after `{{ sku }}`   
  
In the end I decided to start capturing from left to right starting with the opening `<div>` matching `{{ sku }}` (non-capturing) in the middle up until the next starting `<div>` as follows:   
  
`(<div class="form-group">.*(?:{{ sku }}).*)(?:<div class="form-group">)`

Comment: You said you wanted to capture 2 div's ahead of the chosen word...

Comment: And btw that does not match your example: https://regex101.com/r/QkK8LY/1

Comment: You are using `/gm` modifier not `/s` for dot to match newline characters example: https://regex101.com/r/yFPT9o/1 .. The regex still is not the solution as it will start match from the first `<div class="form-group">` through to `{{ sku }}`. I think this will be a task for look ahead and look behind.

Comment: How does my regex not fulfil your requirements? If you explain better I may improve it

Comment: see your regex and test string in v2 https://regex101.com/r/QkK8LY/2 .. I have expanded the test string to give more context / clarity

Comment: Check my edit @TrentRenshaw. I was not matching spaces and variations... This way you don't need to specify an initial pattern and don't need to use lookaheads, but use non-greedy capture.